# Unable to open database (sqlite) in asp.net mvc3 app using spring.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sqlite, spring.net

I am writing an asp.net mvc3 web application. I want to use a sqlite database. Unfortunatly I get an SqliteException saying "unable to open database".

> Spring-Version: 1.3.2
>
> NHibernate-Version: 3.2

DbProvider/Connectionstring:

```
<db:provider id="employeesDbProvider"
           provider="SQLite-1.0.72"
           connectionString="Data Source=.\Database\Employees.db3;Version=3;">
</db:provider>
```

Stacktrace:

```
bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum flags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool) in c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLite3.cs:Zeile 239.
bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open() in c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteConnection.cs:Zeile 1022.
bei NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
```

I even tried setting the DataSource to an absolut path (*C:\temp\database\Employees.db3*) but the same SqLiteException is thrown.

Update:

Stacktrace shown on error page:

```
[SQLiteException (0x80004005): Unable to open the database file]
   System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum flags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool) in c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLite3.cs:239
   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open() in c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteConnection.cs:1022
   NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() +155
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare() +41
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper) +105
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory) +151
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners) +1012
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +162
   Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject.NewSessionFactory(Configuration config) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate20\Data\NHibernate\LocalSessionFactoryObject.cs:952
   Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject.AfterPropertiesSet() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate20\Data\NHibernate\LocalSessionFactoryObject.cs:706
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InvokeInitMethods(Object target, String name, IConfigurableObjectDefinition definition) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.cs:1294
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.cs:1890
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Objects\Factory\Support\WebObjectFactory.cs:450
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.cs:921

[ObjectCreationException: Error creating object with name 'employeesSessionFactory' defined in 'file [C:\Develop\ASP.Net-Schulung\Mitarbeiterverwaltung.Web\bin\Config\Spring.Database.config.xml] line 16' : Initialization of object failed : Unable to open the database file]
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.cs:938
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:2144
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Objects\Factory\Support\WebObjectFactory.cs:299
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:2065
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObject(String name) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:1826
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.PreInstantiateSingletons() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\DefaultListableObjectFactory.cs:505
   Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.Refresh() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\AbstractApplicationContext.cs:1017
   Spring.Context.Support.MvcApplicationContext..ctor(MvcApplicationContextArgs args) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Web.Mvc\Context\Support\MvcApplicationContext.cs:75
   Spring.Context.Support.MvcApplicationContext..ctor(String name, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] configurationLocations) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Web.Mvc\Context\Support\MvcApplicationContext.cs:47
   _dynamic_Spring.Context.Support.MvcApplicationContext..ctor(Object[] ) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Web.Mvc\Context\Support\MvcApplicationContext.cs:50
   Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeConstructor.Invoke(Object[] arguments) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Reflection\Dynamic\DynamicConstructor.cs:116
   Spring.Context.Support.RootContextInstantiator.InvokeContextConstructor(ConstructorInfo ctor) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:563
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextInstantiator.InstantiateContext() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:508
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parentContext, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:351
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.Create(Object parent, Object configContext, XmlNode section) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:289

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': Unable to open the database file]
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult) +199
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1153
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1468
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey) +41
   System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName) +52
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(String sectionName) +57
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String configKey) +6
   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName) +78
   Spring.Util.ConfigurationUtils.GetSection(String sectionName) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Util\ConfigurationUtils.cs:71
   Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext.GetContextInternal(String virtualPath) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:335
   Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext.GetRootContext() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:223
   Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule.Init(HttpApplication app) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebSupportModule.cs:175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +172
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +43
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +828
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +327
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole exception message, inner exception (if any) and stack trace.

Comment: There is no inner exception. I added the complete stacktrace shown on the error page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did a quick test with SQLite, Spring.Net and it fails with the same error, however when I used slashes instead of backslashes in the connection string it magically starts to work.

```
<db:provider id="employeesDbProvider" 
    provider="SQLite-1.0.72"
    connectionString="Data Source=c:/temp/Database/Sample.db3;Version=3;">
</db:provider>
```

**Edit:**
I tested a bit further to find out where the file is stored if I use the dot prefix e.g. `./Employees.db3`. In IISExpress it is stored in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express` most likely not what you did expect.

In IIS7 it simply fails with the `Unable to open the database file` error, ihmo because it tries to write to the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder.

The safest bet is to use

```
<db:provider id="employeesDbProvider" 
    provider="SQLite-1.0.72"
    connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Sample.db3;Version=3;">
</db:provider>
```

Wich is the `App_Data` folder of your MVC application.

I used SQLite 1.0.80.0 for my tests. Keep in mind that SQLite does not create the directory and needs ACL write rights.