# Unable to open database file after changing connection string, SQLite, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite, database-connection

I have a ASP.NET MVC solution with 2 projects: DAL and web project.
I used to connect to my SQLite database using local file path in connection string of both projects' web.config files:

Web.configs of DAL and Web projects:

```
<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;
provider=System.Data.SQLite;
provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Myproj\Myproj.db3&quot;'" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Everything was working fine, and then I needed to change connection string using `DataDirectory`, so that I could correctly deploy the website. I added the db file into `App_Data` folder of **WEB project** and both web.configs changed to:

```
<add name="DBEntities"
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SQLite;
    provider connection string='data source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\Myproj.db3&quot;'" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now, I can connect to the db extract data via code, but I cannot open database in server explorer and use designer, the error is: "Unable to open database file".

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Check out the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292875/unable-to-open-database-sqlite-in-asp-net-mvc3-app-using-spring-net  this may help or at least give you some clues

Comment: I'm using DataDirectory as suggested, but my problem is only with server explorer designer, because db is accessible via code.

Answer (score 0):

I used like this. If you want you can try.

```
private readonly static string ConnectionKey = @"C:\Users\Mehmeto\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\......\bin\myDB.sqlite";

    public static SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {

        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + ConnectionKey + ";Version=3;", true);
        return conn;
    }
```